# html visualized upside down by RStudio after knitting an R mark down document

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

Since I changed my laptop for a new m1 macbook every time I knit a document the html visualized in Rstudio is upside down, while when I open it with a browser it has no problem. I tried to update the knitr package but with no success.
I paste my sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.16

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.2    rsconnect_0.8.16  htmltools_0.5.1.1 tools_4.0.2       yaml_2.2.1        rmarkdown_2.3     knitr_1.32        xfun_0.22         digest_0.6.25    
[10] rlang_0.4.7       evaluate_0.14
```

And here the link to the upside down weird visualization:

[image: knitted html file]

The same happens when I try to use git integrated in RStudio, making impossible to use the integration.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, you should report it to the RStudio github.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I think the only solution is to knit the file (command + K) and open the resulting .html file using a browser.

For reference, I am running Big Sur on an intel i5 processor. I think it's a Mac OS problem rather than the M1 chip.

Alternatively, you can try [installing a legacy version](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages) of `knitr`.

Comment: Thanks! Using the browser did it for me. At least that part is not messed up (just R's visualization).